# How to create custom themes in Anycharts Qlik extension

Tags: qliksense, anychart

I am trying to create custom themes in our Anycharts Qlik sense extension. I used the following article as a guide, https://www.anychart.com/blog/2019/01/16/qlik-data-visualization-custom-drawing/

The article names these files as the key to adding themes:

"To add a custom theme to the AnyChart Qlik Extension, edit the file at ..\Users\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Extensions\AnyChart-Qlik\lib\themes-combined.js by putting the code of your custom theme at the end.

To use the theme by default in the future, edit the config.js file at ..\Users\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Extensions\AnyChart-Qlik"

I cannot find these files (or even the "lib" folder mentioned) in either a desktop or enterprise installation.

has anyone:
1) found these files/folders ?
2) successfully created a custom theme for teh Anycharts qlik sense extension ?

Thanks

Already searched Qlik installation for the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the article is related to the 2.4 version of Qlik. But the current version is 3.x, and the feature is not supported there. Perhaps it'll be restored in the future.

Comment: thanks for reply,  we are using Qlik Sense April 2019, is there any way to create custom themes ?

Comment: As I said, the current version doesn't support this feature but maybe will in the future.